# Prove or Disprove that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$? (Limit).

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^4y}{x^4+y^2}$ whenever $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$. and $f(x,y)=(0,0)$ otherwise. 
> Prove or disprove: $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$.

My attempt: 
I am trying to prove it by showing that $\epsilon \to 0$ when $\Delta x,\Delta y \to 0$ in this definition: 
$f(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y)-f(x,y)=f_x(x,y)\Delta x+f_y \Delta y + \epsilon\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}$. 

I have checked by definition that $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$. 
And so $f(\Delta x, \Delta y)=\epsilon\sqrt{\Delta x^2+ \Delta y^2}$ Which gives me: 
$$\frac{(\Delta x)^4(\Delta y)}{[(\Delta x)^4 + (\Delta y)^2]\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+ (\Delta y)^2}}=\epsilon$$But now  I got stuck trying to show that $\epsilon \to 0$, I am not sure how to deal with this limit and would appreciate any help and explanations on your thoughts (What did you think when you saw this limit, like did you know it converges to $0$ just by looking at it? What I'm trying to say is I would appreciate explanations on your thoughts "behind the scenes" that led you to use your method). 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$. So, if $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$, then $Df_{(0,0)}$ is the null function, which happens if and only if$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0.$$And this is indeed true. For any two real numbers $a$ and $b$ you have$$ab\leqslant\frac{a^2+b^2}2,$$and therefore$$\left(\forall(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\right):|x^2y|\leqslant\frac{x^4+y^2}2.\tag1$$But then, if $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$,\begin{align}0&\leqslant\left|\frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\\&=\frac{x^4|y|}{(x^4+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\&\leqslant\frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\&\leqslant\frac{|x|}2,\end{align}and therefore, by the squeeze theorem, $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Thanks so much, beautiful proof, I have always seen that inequality you used as $\frac{ab}{a^2 + b^2} \le \frac{1}{2}$, never realized that I could use it in different ways! this is very eye opening.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thinking about it now, what happens when $(x,y)=(0,0)$? if the function is defined to be $0$ there, and you proved that for every $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$, that means the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$? what if $f(0,0)=2$, would that matter?

Comment: Sure. Then $f$ would be discontinuous at $(0,0)$ and therefore not differentiable there.

Answer (score 1):

We can do a variable substitution, just let $x^2=rcos\vartheta, y=rsin\vartheta$, you could prove this is a equivalent substitution. Then the equation could be turned into $$f(r,\vartheta)=\frac {r^3sin\vartheta cos^2\vartheta}{r^2}=rsin\vartheta cos^2\vartheta$$and when $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0),(r,\vartheta)$ simutaneously converges to $(0,0)$, so that we could easily know $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$

Comment: Wow that's a really cool solution, I've never seen a polar substitution with $x^2$, could you please explain intuitively why it's allowed?

Comment: the intuition is to make the one under fraction to be $r^2$, it's rationality is being kinda Coordinate transformation

Comment: Very cool, this opened my mind to many uses of polar coordinates in limits! thanks!

Comment: glad to help you, but don't forget to prove its equivalence! : )